# Gauss: The study of Euler's works...

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, math-history

I keep coming across this quote by Gauss but I haven't actually been able to locate the original source: “The Study of Euler’s works will remain the best school for the various fields of mathematics and nothing will replace it.” If someone can help me with this I would be very grateful. Thanks!

Comment: This may be better placed over at History of Science and Mathematics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is taken from a letter to Fuß, September 11, 1849: "Das Studium der Werke Eulers bleibt die beste Schule in den verschiedenen Gebieten der Mathematik und kann durch nichts anderes ersetzt werden". According to 
http://gauss.gwi.uni-muenchen.de/
extracts from this correspondence were published by Fuchs in 1976.